# Filter column in pandas and convert to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, which contains some pretty infiltered data

```
df['Q53']
OUTPUT:
0      Hvor mange timer træner din virksomhed medarbe...
3                                                    NaN
4                                                    NaN
5                                                    NaN
6                                                      2
7                                                    NaN
8                                                     10
9                                                    NaN
10                                                    50
11                                                   NaN
12                                                     ?
13                                                     ?
14                                                     8
15                                                   NaN
16                                                     2
17                                                     0
18                                                     1
19                                                     1
20                                                     5
21                                             7x3 timer
22                                                   NaN
23                                               8 timer
24                                                   NaN
25                                                     0
26                                                     8
27                                                   NaN
```

the issue now, is that i want to just have the integers left in the column, and then cast them as a float, so i can do some data visualization with the column.

I was wondering if i could do some standardized filtering, but i could not get get it to work.

Is there an operation, where i can filter out all `NaN` and `String` values, and just be left with a value, that could be casted into a `float` or `int`

Comment: Values `8 timer, 7x3 timer` is matched to some number? Or not?

Comment: @jezrael `8 timer` should be interpreted to just `8` and `7X3 timer` to `21`. However this might be out of scope for the question

Comment: hmm, if interesting about solution the best post new question.

Comment: @jezrael i tried implementing your solution, and i see, that maybe it would work better, can you post it again, than i will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to numeric and then remove misisng values:

```
df['Q53'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Q53'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Q53'])
print (df)
     Q53
6    2.0
8   10.0
10  50.0
14   8.0
16   2.0
17   0.0
18   1.0
19   1.0
20   5.0
25   0.0
26   8.0
```

EDIT: I sugggest not use [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), here is solution for extract numeric with `x` between, convert to floats and multiple between.

Then replace missing values with all numeric extracted by `\d+` patter in regex and converted to numbers.

Last remove missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
dfx = df['Q53'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)x(\d+)').astype(float).prod(axis=1, min_count=1)

num = df['Q53'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)

df['Q53'] = dfx.fillna(pd.to_numeric(num, errors='coerce'))
df = df.dropna(subset=['Q53'])
print (df)
     Q53
6    2.0
8   10.0
10  50.0
14   8.0
16   2.0
17   0.0
18   1.0
19   1.0
20   5.0
21  21.0
23   8.0
25   0.0
26   8.0
```

Comment: I tried adding this solution to another column with larger values, and i get the values in this format.
`6      5.000000e+05
8      1.000000e+05
10     1.000000e+05
16     5.000000e+08
18     2.000000e+06
19     0.000000e+00
20     2.500000e+06
2`

Comment: yes the isue, is that it is of type `object` and not string

Comment: @baileyhaldwin - So not diplay problem? If write to file, still `e` ?

Comment: here is the error message `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: So `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)` convert values to strings? If remove it, then get `e` numbers?

Comment: before all the other function calls?

Comment: I think yes. It only change diplaying of floats.

Comment: i addedd `fx = df['Q53'].astype(str)str.extract('(\d+)x(\d+)').astype(float).prod(axis=1, min_count=1)` and made it work

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `isdigit` to select only `True` columns.

```
df[df['Q53'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]
```

Comment: Based on OP's additional request in the comments it is obvious this will not work, rather than using `eval`, I think its better to understand all the criteria in your combinations before updating the answer.